# Aggregating (fold) hash sets to a struct requires clone

Tags: rust

I'm trying to aggregating a simple struct, where it has a hash set and integer, using `fold`. I was able to do eventually, but I needed to use `clone`, which I feel inefficient as it requires copies.

Playground link is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d57f01e4c6f195b736d1e5ef8e1e7498).

The code is here:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

struct Result {
    value: usize,
    names: HashSet<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let results = [
        Result {
            value: 10,
            names: HashSet::from(["a".to_string(), "b".to_string()]),
        },
        Result {
            value: 20,
            names: HashSet::from(["a".to_string(), "c".to_string()]),
        },
    ];

    // Aggregating to the same struct type requires clone.
    let aggregated = results.iter().fold(
        Result {
            value: 0,
            names: HashSet::new(),
        },
        |mut acc, x| {
            acc.value += x.value;
            // Q1: This doesn't work. Why can't I do that?
            // acc.names.extend(&x.names);
            // Q2: I had to use clone. Is it inefficient?
            acc.names.extend(x.names.clone());
            acc
        },
    );
    println!("Aggregated: {}, {}", aggregated.value, aggregated.names.len());

    // Aggregating to a hash set works nicely.
    let aggregated = results.iter().fold(HashSet::new(), |mut acc, x| {
        // Q3: I can pass as &. No any copy, right?
        acc.extend(&x.names);
        acc
    });
    println!("Aggregated: {}", aggregated.len());
}
```

Q1: I don't understand why I can't pass as a reference. In Q3, I was able to do so. This is the error, which I don't clearly understand.

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<&HashSet<String> as IntoIterator>::Item == String`
  --> src/main.rs:29:30
   |
29 |             acc.names.extend(&x.names);
   |                       ------ ^^^^^^^^ expected struct `String`, found `&String`
   |                       |
   |                       required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
note: required by a bound in `extend`
```

Q2: Using `clone` makes it work. But does it mean there was literally a copy of the hash set? The hash set can contain a million of items. So, I'd like to avoid it.

Q3: Super interesting. If I don't aggregate to a hash set only, I was able to pass a reference to do `extend`.

Comment: Hint: your second `aggregated` is actually of type `HashSet<&String>`.

Answer (score 2):

I think your main problem is using `.iter()` instead of `.into_iter()`:

```rust
// `.into_iter()` iterates over the elements by value,
// consuming the underlying structure.
let aggregated: Result = results.into_iter().fold(
    Result {
        value: 0,
        names: HashSet::new(),
    },
    |mut acc, x| {
        acc.value += x.value;
        acc.names.extend(x.names);
        acc
    },
);
println!("Aggregated: {}, {}", aggregated.value, aggregated.names.len());
```

1. You can't pass as reference because a reference to a `String` is not the same as a `String`. You can only get a reference because `x` is a reference to a `Result`.
2. Yes, `clone` can be inefficient because it deep copies whatever data is in the data structure and can result in a new heap allocation.
3. That's because you're aggregating into a `HashSet<&String>` rather than a `HashSet<String>`:

```rust
// `.iter()` iterates over each element by reference,
// leaving the original data structure untouched.
let aggregated: HashSet<&String> = results.iter().fold(HashSet::new(), |mut acc, x| {
    // No cloning necessary because you're storing
    // references to each name in the set.
    acc.extend(&x.names);
    acc
});
println!("Aggregated: {}", aggregated.len());
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2f61914d97bc3caf13c138307be47739)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the mystery. Now I do get it.